# How to force HTTPS in a Django project using Cloudinary?

Tags: django, cloudinary

I am using Cloudinary in my Django project to upload and store my images.

Something like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    logo = CloudinaryField('Logo', blank=True, null=True)
```

In my serializers, if I call something like:

```
mymodel = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
return mymodel.logo.url
```

What is being returned is a cloudinary url but only with http. How do I fix this? How do I get https?

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/reverse/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloudinary response holds both `url` (HTTP) and `secure_url` (HTTPS).

Please try:

```
return mymodel.logo.secure_url
```

Instead of

```
return mymodel.logo.url
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `secure` in settings:

```
cloudinary.config(cloud_name = "", api_key = "", api_secret = "", secure = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that's getting errors with `secure_url`, modifying the `url_options` dictionary did the trick for me:

```
mymodel = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
# Adding 'secure' to url_options
# Cloudinary source code seems to look for this key when building urls
mymodel.logo.url_options.update({'secure':True})
return mymodel.logo.url
```